# Form radio doesn't insert into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have a test with three radio options, and for each option being pressed I want that option to increase on 1 or whatever number I want and then add the count of each radio button being pressed to the database.

I have such table structure: two fields: color and clicks. Color has values: green, red, yellow.

```
<?php

$a=mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

$b=mysql_select_db('xxxx',$a);


if ($_POST['submit']){


if ($_POST['color']=='green'){


$query='UPDATE tester SET clicks = clicks+1 WHERE color = "green"';

mysql_query($query);


 }

 if ($_POST['color']=='red'){


$query='UPDATE tester SET clicks = clicks+1 WHERE color = "red"';

mysql_query($query);

 }

 if ($_POST['color']=='yellow'){

$query='UPDATE tester SET clicks = clicks+1 WHERE color = "yellow"';

mysql_query($query);

 }

 }

?>

<form action="indexni.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" />Yellow<br>
<input type ="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value which you want to set i.e. clicks = **clicks**+1 in that what is the value of **clicks**?

If the value of **clicks** is the previous value of **clicks** of your table then first you have to write query of select on that table to get value of **clicks**.

Comment: value of clicks of each color is 0

Comment: Then write $clicks = 0  after $_POST['submit'] and change query to 
$query='UPDATE tester SET clicks = '".$clicks."'+1 WHERE color = "green"';